# add custom fonts name in kendo editor

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I have a kendo editor which looks like the below

```
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
    tools: [
        "bold",
        "fontSize",
        "foreColor",
        "backColor",
        {
            name: "fontName",
            items: [
                { text: "Andale Mono", value: "Andale Mono" },
                { text: "Arial", value: "Arial" },
                { text: "Arial Black", value: "Arial Black" },
                { text: "Book Antiqua", value: "Book Antiqua" },
                { text: "Comic Sans MS", value: "Comic Sans MS" },
                { text: "Courier New", value: "Courier New" },
                { text: "Georgia", value: "Georgia" },
                { text: "Helvetica", value: "Helvetica" },
                { text: "Impact", value: "Impact" },
                { text: "Symbol", value: "Symbol" },
                { text: "Tahoma", value: "Tahoma" },
                { text: "Terminal", value: "Terminal" },
                { text: "Times New Roman", value: "Times New Roman" },
                { text: "Trebuchet MS", value: "Trebuchet MS" },
                { text: "Verdana", value: "Verdana" },
                { text: "Webdings", value: "Webdings" },
                { text: "Wingdings", value: "Wingdings" },
                { text: "Calibri", value: "Calibri" },
                //{ text: "tamil-SARURG", value: "tamil-SARURG" }

            ]
        },
        {
            name: "custom",
            tooltip: "Add page break",
            exec: function (e) {
                var editor = $(this).data("kendoEditor");
                editor.exec("inserthtml", { value: "<p STYLE='page-break-before: always'>Page break here!</p>" });
            }
        }
    ],
});
```

Now I want to add custom font name in my kendo editor, the font name is called

> tamil-SARURG

I also added the following line in my code

> { text: "tamil-SARURG", value: "tamil-SARURG" }

but it did not worked.

how can I add custom font name in kendo editor